# JVM passing subshell parameters

Tags: bash

I need to pass a subshell result to my java application however I hit some bash issues. What is the proper way writing of this command?

```
java  $(echo "-server -Xshare:off -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='myscript xxxx'") -version
```

The last `myscript xxx` is the problem here. It is including a space and causing some wrong interpretation.

Any clue for fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point in using a childprocess doing an `echo` here. I would simply write

```
java  -server -Xshare:off -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="$whatever_you_need" -version
```

Comment: I asked in this way because I simplified the question for removing unnecessary parts. It is actually read from a file.

Comment: @Cemo : Perhaps it is not as unnecessary as you think. You better provide more details, on how you actually want to invoke Java here. I suggest that you either ask a new question with more information, and edit your question, but **amend** the new details. Don't erase the old text you have already written.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but not tested,

`java -server -Xshare:off -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="'${<myscript xxxx}'" -version`